# find the probability that two experiments matches in at least one number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have an urn with $N$ different balls numbered from $1$ to $N$. One experiment consist in sustracting $k$ balls without reposition.

Find the probability that if you perform 2 experiments there will be at least one number appearing in both experiments, for example: in $1,3,5,7,9$   and $1,2,10,11,12$ both experiments contain the number $1$.

I'm not sure if the answer has a simple form because I asked this to myself. I was playing a game and I needed the answer for the case $N=74$ and $k=5$ ( I don't know the answer for this case yet either).

The total number of possible experiments is $\binom{N}{k}$, therefore if I perform $2$ experiments the total cases is given by $\binom{N}{k}^2$. I don't know how to compute the favorable cases.
My idea is to start with an specific experiment (let's say $1,2,3,4,5$) and compute the number of experiments that contain any of this numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just imagine that you draw the balls $1$ to $k$ in the first draw.  Otherwise you can renumber the balls.  Now ask the chance you don't get a number from $1$ to $k$ in the second draw and subtract from $1$.  You get 
$$1-\frac {N-k \choose k}{N \choose k}$$